# the_post_thumbnail not resizing

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm using the following code:

```
<?php if (the_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But the thumbnail is appearing full size. Same applies if I use `(array(200,150))`. My "Media" settings are set correctly (thumbnails at 288 max width, 500 max height); I've checked the `uploads` directory to see if the images have been resized and they have.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the answer to match my latest comment:

Changing `<?php if (the_post_thumbnail()): ?>` to `<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>` will probably solve things.

Also, some must have developer plugins when working with featured images:

- [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)
- [AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/)

Comment: Thanks mate. I installed the AJAX version instead in case I have to do this in future (we'll have 12,000+ images) but to no avail - same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I've misread the last bit of your question. Changing `<?php if (the_post_thumbnail()): ?>` to `<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>` will probably solve things.

Comment: Perfect! :) I'll accept your original answer, feel free to edit it to incorporate your latest comment.